# Using Windows Multipoint for gaming

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, multipoint-server-2011

I have a pretty powerful computer and graphics card, my specs are 16gb of ram, and a 3.6ghz quad core processor.  I also have 3 monitors.

I was wondering if I could set it up to run League of Legends for me and my friends?

Is Windows Multipoint a completely separate operating system, or is it an add-on?

Also, I have tried virtual box, but I can not get my graphics card drivers installed onto it.

Comment: "Also, I have tried virtual box, but I can not get my graphics card drivers installed onto it." That's because VirtualBox doesn't have your graphics card.

Comment: Exactly, but is it possible?

Edit:  What I mean, is virtual box uses a different graphics adapter, apparently, but I would rather use my graphics card.

Comment: VirtualBox has VirtualBox's virtual video card.

Comment: Yes, can I install my own onto it?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What are you actually asking? Are you asking if it 's possible for your computer to run 3 virtual machines simultaneously so your friends can all play LoL?